# Win32 Restart application after updating

Tags: c++, winapi

While self-updating my own executable ([here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5163875/TU-The-Easy-Update-Library-for-Your-Projects) 's my library), I rename it to another file (Windows allows renaming of a running app) and save the updated version as the old name.

So if it's `app.exe` and app is updated, it renames itself to say `app.old`, and puts the updated `app.exe` in place to be run the next time the user runs it.

Now, is there a way to tell Windows to start `app.exe` as long as `app.old` dies?  I saw [`RegisterApplicationRestart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/recovery/registering-for-application-restart) but I'm not sure if it will restart the application. I want an instant restart so the update is transparent to the user.

If I start `app.exe` from `app.old` and `app.exe` tries to update itself and `app.old` is in use, it won't be able to self-rename.

I could pass a command line parameter to `app.exe` to force it not to check for updates, but is there a way with the API?

Edit: [I found this](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/07/28/restart-app-programmatically/#oK1vve5miovTFD8S.97), but it is for UWP only.

Comment: Windows has ways to get a unique temporary file name, why would you not just rename yourself to that, rather than the fixed `app.old`?

Comment: @paxdiablo - this will be only work only in case *app.exe* located on the same volume as and *temp* folder. also begin from some win 10 version possible delete and running exe, but this will be not work for previous versions

Comment: @paxdiablo app.old was just an example

Comment: @RbMm, `GetTempFileName` allows you to specify the directory for generating a unique file, there's no requirement that it exist in the temp folder.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, that's fine, just use a temp (unique) file name in the current directory, you will not have any conflicts.

Comment: @paxdiablo my problem is to have the old one executable terminate *before* the new one begins the self updating process, without a command line, if such a way exists with Windows.

Comment: @paxdiablo - and what sense in this case call `GetTempFileName` if file will be not placed in temp folder ? unique name we can generate and without this api, but anyway file will be not automatically deleted. so it not temporary

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be auto-deleted, you could have the real executable manually delete other files after a certain time. By ensuring the files are renamed to a pattern like `app.old.<uniqueBit>`, you could just delete files of that pattern greater than a day old (for example).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis - raname self exe to some random name and pass this name in command line to new exe (possible and without this) for it delete old

Comment: The problem is not how to delete the old one, but how to ensure that the old one will be terminated and the new one will be restarted. If the new one is restated and the old one is still running, no deletion will be possible.

Comment: Michael, just start the new one from the old one.

Comment: Yep. Start the new exe, passing the PID of the running process as a command line arg, and then terminate. When the new exe gets that PID, it waits on the process that is terminating. Then it can update. But really, this isn't the best way to handle this. Far better to have a dedicated updater so you simply don't need to juggle this kind of stuff.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can do that, the question is whether Windows can do it for me.

Comment: you can create new exe with temporary name (say *~*), than pass self process handle (not *pid* which is unreliable ) to new started process and exit. new process wait for old exit and then rename self from temporary name to "normal" name. you can even preserve original command line. POC code - https://pastebin.com/ryxr6GJH

Comment: If you've just updated yourself, surely the new one isn't going to find another update straight away?